# Оптимизировать код C++

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Надо оптимизировать код программы как можно сильнее

Задача 
http://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=5&id_topic=114&id_problem=705

Сам код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
long long a;
long long j = -1, ans;
vector <long long> n;
long long maxi = -100;

int main()
{
    cin >> a;
    long long tmp_g = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        cin >> tmp_g;
        n.push_back(tmp_g);
    }

    while (1){
        long long hom = j + 1;
        for(int z = j+1; z < a; z++){
            if(n[z] > n[hom])
                hom = z;
        }
        ans += (hom - j) * n[hom];
        j = hom;
        if (j == a - 1 ) 
        {
            break; 
        }
    }

    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что именно вы подразумеваете под "оптимизировать"? Ваш код не проходит по времени и вы хотите решить задачу? Или, например, вы хотите поставить какой-то рекорд?

Comment: Поставить личный рекорд о быстром выполнении задачи

Comment: Уточните, оптимизацию по какому параметру вы жаждите?

Comment: скорость и оперативка

Comment: все величины до от 1 до 100 - измените long long на int. Задача решается в один проход с конца массива - избавьтесь от вложенного цикла. При чтении из файла ваш массив постояно растет  - поскольку конечный размер известен используйте reserve чтобы не было лишних копирований при resize of the vector

Comment: Неформал может продавать волосы **несколько раз** за эти N дней?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наилучшая оптимизация - всегда начинается с подбора оптимального алгоритма:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> c(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> c[i];

    int cost = c[n-1], sum = cost;

    for(int j = n-2; j >= 0; --j)
        sum += (cost = max(cost,c[j]));

    cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: а почему `if (c[j] > cost) cost = c[j];` а не `cost = max(cost, c[j])`?)

Comment: @pavel А есть разница?

Comment: не знаю. Привычка всегда писать максимум... https://godbolt.org/g/W5j7dz вроде условного перехода нету - уже хорошо.

Comment: @pavel Ну, VC++ 2015 дает одинаковый код, без условного перехода... Но в принципе это позволяет сократить исходный текст, так что вношу исправление в ответ...

Comment: Написал алгоритм "в лоб" - O(N²). Он так же решает продавать шевелюру именно в те дни, когда цена возрастает с конца. Сижу, мучаюсь, и никак не могу понять это на уровне матана. Не могли бы вы пояснить парой строк человеческого текста? Может еще кому полезно будет.

Comment: А, все докумекал. В цикле с конца при продаже в любые дни, цена в которые ниже максимальной, мы отнимаем длину волос, умноженную на максимальную цену для произведений с более низкими ценами.

Comment: Ну, можно и так сложно. По простому - ну вот последние волосы можно продать только в последний день. А предпоследние? Либо в последний, либо в предпоследний - если цена в предпоследний выше. А еще днем раньше?... Вот примерно так и идем...

Answer (score -1):

Ну я не знаю, насколько этот код вам покажется оптимальней, но я предлагаю вам свой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,s=0,prev;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    auto x = a.begin();
    while (x!=a.end())
    {
        prev = x - a.begin();
        x = max_element(x, a.end());
        s += (*x)*(x-a.begin() - prev+1);
        x++;
    }
    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Я бы еще убрал все лишние вычисления, облегчив жизнь оптимизатору:

    `int n,s=0;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];

    for(auto x = a.begin(), e = a.end(); x != e;)
    {
        auto y = max_element(x,e);
        s += (*y)*(y-x+1);
        x = y + 1;
    }`

Comment: @9Pasha, почему удалил вопрос про число комбинаций?)

Comment: @diraria, ну если хотите поговорить об этом, то можете каким-то образом дать мне свой контакт(в чем-либо)? Ну вообще задачу я не решил, но не хочу говорить об этом здесь.

Comment: @9Pasha можешь [вк](https://vk.com/write104171944) написать)